Running pwsh.exe with -File never returns
I created simple Test.ps1 script like this:
echo $org = Get-VBOOrganization -Name "OrgName.onmicrosoft.com" >> Test.ps1
echo $org.Id.ToString() >> Test.ps1

Then I run this script with pwsh:
pwsh -File Test.ps1

Script executes, writes output (some guid), but then it never returns back to cmdline
Important note: When I use powershell.exe instead of pwsh.exe then I am correctly returned to cmdline. So this works:
powershell -File Test.ps1

But, I need to use pwsh to use PS7.
I tried to play with -MTA & -NonInteractive parameters, nothing helped.
Would anyone know what else to try?
Thanks a lot!

You probably forgot to mention that to reproduce the issue people might need Import-Module Veeam.Archiver.PowerShell but Veeam's PowerShell module isn't there on most machines. If an issue involves a third party module, and cannot reproduce with other simple test scripts, you should write the question in a very different way.

Problem solved by calling Exit in the end of the script:
[System.Environment]::Exit(0)

